# Dummy sound output - no sound available

Tags: 12.04, sound

I'm on ubuntu 12.04

For some reason, the sound output changed to "dummy output".

I have no idea why.

```
me@me-GeForce6100PM-M2:~$ hwinfo --sound
hal.1: read hal dataprocess 2562: arguments to dbus_move_error() were incorrect, assertion "(dest) == NULL || !dbus_error_is_set ((dest))" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-errors.c line 282.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
libhal.c 3483 : Error unsubscribing to signals, error=The name org.freedesktop.Hal was not provided by any .service files
15: PCI 05.0: 0403 Audio device                                 
  [Created at pci.318]
  Unique ID: CvwD.RQk7jdMXoF7
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:05.0
  Hardware Class: sound
  Model: "nVidia MCP61 High Definition Audio"
  Vendor: pci 0x10de "nVidia Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x03f0 "MCP61 High Definition Audio"
  SubVendor: pci 0x10de "nVidia Corporation"
  SubDevice: pci 0xcb84 
  Revision: 0xa2
  Memory Range: 0xfe024000-0xfe027fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 22 (no events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v000010DEd000003F0sv000010DEsd0000CB84bc04sc03i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
```

ALSO

I installed pavucontrol

I ran it, and on the configuration tab, it says 'No cards available for configuration'.
Please help -- I have no sound!

Thanks so much

Comment: Hi.I have also tried to enter "alsamixer" into the terminal and I get the following. cannot open mixer: No such file or directory. I also tried to run /usr/sbin/alsaconf and it came back with 
bash: /usr/sbin/alsaconf: No such file or directory. I finally tried "pulseaudio", and I got this. E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed. Please help -- it's so frustrating not being able to watch and listen to music and TV. Thanks!

Comment: Basically the soundcard is not detected. me@me-GeForce6100PM-M2:~$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:252: **no soundcards found...**. I then typed in lspci -v and got this... 
00:05.0 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 High Definition Audio (rev a2)
 Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device cb84
 Flags: 66MHz, fast devsel, IRQ 22
 Memory at fe024000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

Comment: Open `Sound` in `System Settings`. Do you see your hardware there?